# Multiple many to many polymorphic relationship problem in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have been working on a project where 2 types of users register.
1. Company
2. Distributor

I have created modules for both and they both have separate authentication modules created using passport.

All working fine and now I want to add a feature which allow to send messages from Companies to Distributor or vise versa.

**Here are my migrations:**

**1. messages**

id

messages

parent_message_id(to handle message thread)

**2. fromables (polymorphic relationship to handle FROM which user the message was sent)**

id

message_id

fromable_id

fromable_type ( 'App\Company' or 'App\Distributor' )

**3. toables (polymorphic relationship to handle TO which user the message was sent)**

id

message_id

toable_id

toable_type ( 'App\Company' or 'App\Distributor' )

**Below is how the relationships are defined in Models:**

1. Company model and Distributor model

```
public function messages_sent()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Message', 'fromable');
}
public function messages_received()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Message', 'toable');
}
```

2. Message model

```
public function from_company()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Company', 'fromable');
}
public function from_distributor()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Distributor', 'fromable');
}

public function to_company()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Company', 'toable');
}
public function to_distributor()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Distributor', 'toable');
}
```

And below is how I access the messages sent and received inside company and distributor controllers.

```
$user = $request->user();
$messages_received = $user->messages_received;
$messages_sent = $user->messages_sent;
```

This works fine all the way upto here.

Now the issue is, when I run below code to receive all the messages 
`$messages_received = $user->messages_received;`

It returns all messages but it doesn't return who sent them. Ofcource messages_received uses **'toable'** relation. And sender ID is under **'fromable'** relation.

Here is where I am not sure how to get the sender details along with all the messages when done **$user->messages_received**

How can I do that?
If there is any different approach to implementing this messaging system, do let me know aswell.

Thank You.

Comment: From what I understand you should be able to do `$user->messages_received->load('to_company')` to get the relation to which company the message is sent?

Comment: Wow, you are a legend. it is no to_company but from_company. I just tried that and it worked. Can you add it to answers and I will mark it as correct answer :)
$user->messages_received->load('from_company');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you should be able to do `$user->messages_received->load('from_company')` to get the relation to which company the message is sent.